# How to use linear regression to determine if a significant difference exists?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, least-squares, linear-model, excel

I have two groups of data on students who took a course over the past year; one group online-only and the other face to face. Each student took two tests: a mid-year test and an end-year test, and both tests were administered in identical circumstances. So I have an Excel table looking something like this:

| Student | Online/F2F | Midyear Score | Endyear Score | Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 50 | 61 | 11 |
| 2 | 1 | 78 | 83 | 5 |
| 3 | 0 | 49 | 66 | 17 |

And so on. in the online column, 0 = online-only and 1 = F2F.

I'd like to know whether there is any significant difference in the change in scores (change = endyear - midyear) using OLS. I'm more familiar with t-test, but I'd like to use OLS since I want to later include other control variables and see their impact on the type of course (online or F2F).

My problem is that I don't know whether to use all the scores (with Diff being dependent variable and Online/F2F being independent variable). If I do it this way, with the online and F2F students mixed up, how will I be able to tell if there is a significant difference between the two from the results? Also, If I include other variables (age and gender) and repeat the model, how can I tell the impact of the new variables on the scores?

I'm using Excel, if that's important.

Thanks in advance?

Comment: This looks like something called [tag:difference-in-difference], and I have my doubts about the viability of such a model in Excel. For more complex statistical modeling like you are doing (difference in difference with covariates), other software will perform better. R and Python are free and should be able to do this without much trouble. SAS, Stata, and Matlab are expensive and might have tools to do this (particularly the first two).

Comment: Apart from the test arrangement and details of the surveying, why would you like to particularly use the linear regression? What do you mean by OLS? Have you considered the ANOVA?

Comment: @CrossV ANOVA *is* a linear regression.

Comment: Do you have the Data Analysis Toolpak enabled? That will add some helpful functionality to Excel. I would start with the basics: correlations, ANOVA. Depending on what you see, you may end up trying a regression with endyear as your dependent, online & midyear your independent, if say OL v. F2F was about change from midyear to endyear. But you may find a regression is not the way to go. Start with the descriptive first.

Comment: @ Dave Please stop spreading misinformation.

Comment: This should be a comment. Once you have sufficient reputation, you will be able to comment to debate the point that I have made, but ANOVA is a linear regression, using the group labels as predictors. If you do not understand this point, please consider searching Cross Validated to see if we have answered your question, and perhaps post a new question if you remain confused.